# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation involve Unwind,Match,Sort &Group

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection named **User** which contains embedded document called **Message**. The embedded document **Message** contains array of **message object** as below :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58e09daa192216e39fd85433"),
  "userId" : "user123",
  "message" : [ 
    {
        "messageId" : "5277941e-9d84-46c3-b927-ef33abbf35f2",
        "dateCreated" : 1491115000,
        "body" : "howdy?",
        "type" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "messageId" : "c2ce0480-bc0d-4393-89d4-27174d323b98",
        "dateCreated" : 1491119000,
        "body" : "i've problem with my account. can you help?",
        "type" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "messageId" : "45b2593c-a960-4066-8723-db2531dd8bab",
        "dateCreated" : 1491100000,
        "body" : "this is urgent",
        "type" : "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

My objective is to sort embedded document **Message** based on **dateCreated** key. I need to translate this mongo query into Spring Data MongoDB :

```
db.user.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$message"}, 
  {$match: {userId: "user123"}},
  {$sort: {"message.dateCreated": 1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id", "message": {"$push": "$message"}}})
```

I've tried the following codes but still getting error :

```
AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("message");
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("userId").in("user123"));
AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Direction.ASC, "message.dateCreated");
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("userId", "message");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwind, match, sort, group);

AggregationResults<User> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class, User.class);
```

Error :

> Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

User class :

```
@Document(collection="user")
public class User {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String userId;
  @Field("message")
  @DBRef
  private List<Message> message;
  //constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Message class :

```
@Document
public class Message {
  private String messageId;
  private long dateCreated;
  private String body;
  private String type;
  //constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Hint :

Based on my research, I'm pretty sure that I need to use **GroupOperationBuilder group = 
 Aggregation.group("userId").push("message")** but I don't really know how to proceed with this as AggregationResults will not allow me to use it in the **mongoTemplate.aggregate()**

Answer (score 0):

Optimize query will be:

```
db.user.aggregate(
 {$match: {userId: "user123"}},
 {$unwind: "$message"}, 
 {$sort: {"message.dateCreated": 1}},
 {$group: {_id: "$_id", "message": {"$push": "$message"}}});
```

If you use this given query first it will filter the documents that match your criteria, then it will unwind the filtered documents.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your entity classes are wrong. Why does Message have `@DBRef` as annotation?

In my opinion it should be like that:

```
@Document(collection="user")
public class User {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String userId;
  @Field("message")
  private List<Message> message;
  //constructor, getter, setter
}

public class Message {
  private String messageId;
  private long dateCreated;
  private String body;
  private String type;
  //constructor, getter, setter
}
```